# How to find out whether two numbers are powers of the same number and those powers

Tags: c, function, math, square-root

So say you are given the numbers `27` and `81`. How would a program that tells you that the 4th root of 81 is 3 and the cubic root of 27 is three. (Both have the root of 3).

```c
x = 16;
y = 4;

foo = same_root(16, 4); // foo = 2

root1 = find_root(16, 2); // root1 = 4
root2 = find_root(4, 2); // root2 = 2
```

Comment: Can you give an example with two numbers, please?

Comment: Not every math homework can be done by a computer :-)

Comment: @Dominique But some computer homework can be done by applying some math first :)

Comment: I mean I know how to do it myself. Just want to figure out how to make the computer do it...

Comment: @SteveSummit I don't see how it solves the problem. It will yield `2` for `10` and `6`.

Comment: And then what if the inputs are powers of numbers that aren't prime.

Comment: Logarithms might also help...

Comment: Check whether the ratio of their logarithms is a rational number, p/q. If so, one is a pth power of a number the other is a qth power of. If you use floating-point arithmetic to calculate the ratio, you will have to make allowance for calculation errors. There are other Stack Overflow questions on how to find rational numbers near a floating-point number.

Comment: As a first step, check the the larger one is divisible by the smaller one. If not, then they are definitely *not* powers of the same integer. If so, then they may be and other tests are needed.

Comment: 16 and 4 have a root of 4 with powers 2 and 1. Do you want the smallest root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `CommonRoot(a,b)`,

you say `x'th root of a = y'th root of b`,

which is the same as  `a^(1/x) = b^(1/y)`

So isolating y :

```
//log_x is log base x
log_b(a^(1/x)) = 1/y
(1/x)log_b(a) = 1/y
x/log_b(a) = y
//Or
x/(log(a)/log(b)) = y
```

This function will take in entry x, which is the x of `x'th root of a` and return the corresponding y of `y'th root of b`. By doing `a^(1/x)` or `b^(1/y)`, you find the common root.

So you can iterate through the values of x, waiting to get an integer y and if you do `b^(1/y)`, you will get a common root. To be mentionned also, this method helps you finding multiple common roots and non-integer common roots.

So here's a pseudo-code example :

```
CommonRoot(float a, float b){

    For(int x = 0; x < max(a,b); x++){ // max(a,b) is just to set a threshold of search, 
                                      //I haven't actually tested this, so I don't know what would be a good threshold
        float y = x/(log(a)/log(b)); // gather a y for an x
        If ( fPart(y) == 0){ // test if y is an integer
            If( fPart(b^(1/y)) == 0){ // the answer might lead to a non-integer common root (such as 1.4 beeing a common root of 1.4^2 and 1.4^5)
                return b^(1/y); //return the common root
            }
        }
    }
    
    return -1; //if it hasn't found anything, return -1 or error.
}
```

Please note that this algorithm will likely return the highest common root, not the lowest.

I had a lot of fun finding an optimized solution for you, I hope I helped :).

Comment: I had actually already found a solution, but it ended up being quite similar to this! I had a for loop that started with two and iterated by 1 until it reached the lower of the two numbers. It checked if the log_i(num1) was an integer and same for num2. If both are integers, return each logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize that simple fact that powers of the same number are divisible by each other. And the product itself is a power of the same root. It means that we can have a simple recursive algorithm as follows:

1. Check if the smaller number divides the larger one.
2. If not - return false (`-1` in the code below)
3. If yes, recursively repeat for the smaller number and the product

Our stopping conditions should be when both numbers are equal, but neither is `1`, because `1` can't be a common root.

Here is C code implementing this idea (for positive numbers):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST(x, y) printf("%d, %d => %d\n", (x), (y), common_root((x),(y)))

int common_root(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    
    if (a == 1 || b == 1)
        return -1;
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }
    
    if (a > b) {
        // Swap to make sure  a < b
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    } 
    
    if ( (b % a) == 0) // Check if `b` divisible by `a`
        return common_root(a, b/a);
    else
        return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    TEST(1,2);
    TEST(2,3);
    TEST(6,10);
    TEST(4, 16);
    TEST(12, 24);
    TEST(27, 81);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2 => -1
2, 3 => -1
6, 10 => -1
4, 16 => 4
12, 24 => -1
27, 81 => 3
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/qAe3VS)